# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when trying to call onchange() method in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-nova

I am using `Laravel Nova` custom tool to create my own template. Nova uses `vuejs` so I'm trying to add my custom form and js logic inside `Tool.vue`.

I run this very simple code to perform `onChange()` event on a select but I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at e (vendor.js?id=52886433f04b87b2c184:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.Yr.e._withTask.o._withTask (vendor.js?id=52886433f04b87b2c184:1)
```

Here is my form:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <heading class="mb-6">Model Register Custom</heading>

        <div>
            <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>
              <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And here is my js logic below that which instead of alert() is producing the error:

```
<script>
let Vue = require('vue');

export default {
    mounted() {
        var vm = new Vue({
            methods: {
                onChange() {
                    alert("dsds");
                }
            }
        })
    },
}
</script>
```

P.S: It works fine with simple javascript simple onChange, but with `vuejs` approach I always get this strange error.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong its shape, you should throw it out of the mounted. As the cycle of lives, the mounted it is already a function, so if you want to call it in the assembly of the screen, you declare the method out of the component, and call it inside the mounted. But in your case it does not make sense to call the function in the mounted, and yes only when you click on an item.
Example.

```
<div id="app">
<heading class="mb-6">Model Register Custom</heading>
        <div>
            <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>
              <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

new Vue({
el: '#app',
methods: {
    onChange() {
        alert("dsds");
    }
}
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/ke8w9czy/4/

Comment: is using the vue-cli ?

Comment: I tried your approach but el cannot find the id since it is not registered. So I need to put it inside mounted method or inside window.onload = function () {}    function. And after that I still get the same error!

Comment: Your is using the vue-cli ?

Comment: no, as I said laravel nova admin panel. And this is inside its custom component